# Nested UserControl event doesn't work with EventTrigger/InvokeCommandAction in MVVM/WPF scenario

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, prism

I'm working with WPF with Prism (MVVM), and trying to build an Inspector for a few classes. One of those classes is Vector3:

```
<Grid x:Name="Vector3Root" Background="White">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <xctk:DoubleUpDown Tag="X" Style="{StaticResource DoubleUpDownStyle}" Value="{Binding X}" ValueChanged="Vector3ValueChanged"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <xctk:DoubleUpDown Tag="Y" Style="{StaticResource DoubleUpDownStyle}" Value="{Binding Y}" ValueChanged="Vector3ValueChanged"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <xctk:DoubleUpDown Tag="Z" Style="{StaticResource DoubleUpDownStyle}" Value="{Binding Z}" ValueChanged="Vector3ValueChanged"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And its code-behind

```
namespace SimROV.WPF.Views{
public partial class Vector3View : UserControl
{
    public Vector3View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly RoutedEvent SettingConfirmedEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("SettingConfirmed", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(Vector3View));

    public event RoutedEventHandler SettingConfirmed
    {
        add { AddHandler(SettingConfirmedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(SettingConfirmedEvent, value); }
    }

    public void Vector3ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(SettingConfirmedEvent));
    }
}}
```

The problem that I'm struggling with is that I can't catch neither of the fired events (`ValueChanged` or `SettingConfirmed`) on another `UserControl`'s ViewModel that is using `Vector3View`:

```
<UserControl
         x:Class="SimROV.WPF.Views.TransformView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SimROV.WPF.Views"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"

mc:Ignorable="d" >

<Grid x:Name="TransformRoot" Background="White">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Position" Margin="5"/>
            <!--<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Vector3Template}"/>-->
            <views:Vector3View x:Name="PositionVector3">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SettingConfirmed">
                        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PositionValueChangedCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </views:Vector3View>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Rotation" Margin="5"/>
            <!--<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Vector3Template}"/>-->
            <views:Vector3View x:Name="RotationVector3" SettingConfirmed="RotationValueChangedEvent"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

At this point I CAN catch `SettingConfirmed` with `RotationValueChangedEvent` on code-behind, but since I'm following MVVM pattern, that doesn't work for me, which is why I'm using `EventTrigger` and `InvokeCommandAction` to catch those events on `TransformViewModel`, but those never get fired.
Here it's the `TransformViewModel`:

```
namespace SimROV.WPF.ViewModels{
public class TransformViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private ICommand _positionCommand;

    public ICommand PositionValueChangedCommand => this._positionCommand ?? (this._positionCommand = new DelegateCommand(PositionChanged));
    private void PositionChanged()
    {

    }
    public TransformViewModel()
    {

    }
}}
```

`PositionChanged` just never gets fired and I can't understand why at all.

I don't know if this is relevant, but Transform is an element of an `ObservableCollection<IComponent>` at another ViewModel, which is being presented by a `ListView` with a `ItemContainerStyle`, that has a `ContentPresenter` with a ContentTemplateSelector inside.

Can someone point me out on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the DataContext of the Vector3View? Probably not a TransformViewModel.

Comment: Just realized I did forget to add prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" to both TransformView and Vector3View, but that didn't result in anything new. 
As a matter of fact, Vector3 will just be like a property in many different classes, so I cant hardcode it to Transform.
Is it possible to set its DataContext programatically from another UserControl?

Comment: Setting <views:Vector3View x:Name="PositionVector3" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"> doens't make a difference either

Comment: Why would you set the DataContext of the UserControl to itself? You need to set it to an instance of TransformViewModel for the binding to the command to work.

Comment: I'm really sorry! I'm still new to WPF/Prism and thus having this kind of silly mistakes. Setting PositionVector3.DataContext to this.DataContext at TransformView.xaml.cs solved my issue.
Thank you deeply for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `EventTrigger` and `InvokeCommandAction` should work just fine provided that the `DataContext` of the `Vector3View` actually is a `TransformViewModel` so the binding to the `PositionValueChangedCommand` property succeeds.